# 'Slider Control' kind of controls in Cocos2d help

Tags: user-controls, cocos2d-iphone, slider

I am making a game in Cocos2d. I want there to be a dotted line that follows the user's finger. I want the line to be straight. The problem is, how do I check to see how many 'dots' will fit in the distance between the ball and where the user is touching? And make it follow in a STRAIGHT line between the ball's position and the finger's position? So here's a re-clarification:

The ball sits still on the left side of the screen, and is halfway up the screen. The user drags their finger, and a dotted line is drawn between the ball's position and the touch's position. I have a 'dot' image to be used, and I would like it to be used as the dots in the line. So it will have to recreate the sprite as many times as it will fit in the area between the two points. Please tell me if you want me to clarify further, Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I would make a CCNode object called dottedLine or something.

The dot image would be a sprite that gets added as a child of the node (multiple times).

I would work out the path from ball to finger touch using Trigonometry/Pythagoras theorem.

For creating the line:

From point 0, the ball, i would add 15-20 pixels towards the touch point along the path, and place a dot, I'd repeat this until I reached the end of the line.

Every dot that was placed I would increment a counter, and set that number as the integer tag of that sprite for use in an update method.

Every time the cctouchesmoved method gets called, i'd call an update method on the dottedLine object.

This method would check the distance between the ball and touch point, divide it by the number of dots currently children of the object and remove or add any that are needed. Recreating the sprites every time you move your finger would be messy and wasteful, so reusing your dots and just setting them new positions as the path between ball and touch point changes would probably be best.

I'm not going to provide you code, i think i've explained more than enough of the working out for you to do some googling and work this out.

Comment: could you PLEASE place some code, so i can better understand what you are getting at

Comment: which area of my explanation do you require assistance with?

I'm not going to code the whole thing for you.